# Py2exe doesn't find MSVC90.dll

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-c++, wxpython, py2exe

First of all, I know this is a common error, but I followed all the instructions posted here and in this [tutorial](http://py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step52) but I think the answers are outdated (most of them are from 2010, 2011 and I'm running Windows 10).

I'm using:

- Python 2.7 (32 bits)
- wxPython 3.0.2
- pymssql 2.1.1
- Windows 10

The thing is when I install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2008, it doesn't appear in the folder `C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\` but it appears installed. If I ignore the dll, when I try to open the file, it stays MSVCR90.dll is missing...

Does anyone have any clue or have done it in Windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know for Windows 10, but (with w7) I found them at : C:/Windows/winsxs/x86_microsoft.vc90(...)/

Comment: Okay, I have the dlls, but now where should I put them to look? And Why if I have them, it says when I ignore the dll that I don't have them?)

Comment: Either you put it in the dist or in PythonXX/DLLs, that's what i did and it works fine
The problem (and I would like to get an answer about it too) is that in the end of the execution of py2exe it says that you cant distribute this file... so i actually don't really know how to do to get it work without distributing it.
And i dont know why it told you that you didnt have them.

Comment: I'll stick around because I am in similar problems as you are... :D

Comment: Check the following links out: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ca01e41d-249a-4c35-96bf-4168a4b4225e/can-i-redistribute-msvcr90dll?forum=visualstudiogeneral and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/326922

Answer (score 1):

on the wxPython wiki is some information I and other put together.  Not updated to Py2.7 but the same approach works, you just need to get the correct dll's.

http://wiki.wxpython.org/Deployment
http://wiki.wxpython.org/py2exe-python26